# $PATH not updated when running docker exec sh -c

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I have the following script in a sh file running in the host:

```bash
printf '\n\n=== Installing asdf ...\n\n'
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c 'git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git /root/.asdf --branch v0.10.2'
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c 'echo ''. /root/.asdf/asdf.sh'' >> /root/.bashrc'
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c 'echo ''. /root/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash'' >> /root/.bashrc'

printf '\n\n=== Installing node/npm using asdf ...\n\n'
NODEJS_VERSION='17.9.0'
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c 'asdf plugin add nodejs'
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c "asdf install nodejs $NODEJS_VERSION"
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c "asdf global nodejs $NODEJS_VERSION"
```

When `asdf plugin add nodejs` line is executed I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: asdf: not found
```

The whole issue is happening because `$PATH` is not being updated after the installation of `asdf`. I tried:

1. to reload .bashrc/.profile after installing `asdf`

```bash
docker container exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" sh -c '. /root/.bashrc'
```

2. to restart the container:

```bash
docker "$CONTAINER_NAME" restart
```

The (not so) weird thing is when I get into the container I can use asdf because, as expected, `$PATH` contains the path to `asdf` folders.

Does anybody knows what I am missing here?

Comment: When you double up single quotes they cancel each other out. `echo ''foo bar''` is exactly the same as just `echo foo bar` with no quotes at all. If you want to have literal single quotes inside syntactic single quotes, you need to end the single-quoted context, switch to a double-quoted context, add a single quote inside the double quotes, then switch back. It looks like this: `echo 'these words are '"'"'quoted'"'"' properly'`

Comment: Anyhow -- `.bashrc` isn't used in noninteractive shells. It's completely normal that changes you make to it won't change how scripts execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `exec` runs a new process which loses all its settings when it terminates. You need to start a new Bash shell *with the correct options* to read `.bashrc` ... or just give up on trying to use its interactive features for noninteractive scripts, and instead put these commands in a script, and then simply run it.

```
docker container exec "$container_name" bash '
printf "%s\n" "=== Installing asdf ..."
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git /root/.asdf --branch v0.10.2
. /root/.asdf/asdf.sh
# . /root/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash

printf "%s\n" "=== Installing node/npm using asdf ..."
nodejs_version="17.9.0"
asdf plugin add nodejs
asdf install nodejs "$nodejs_version"
asdf global nodejs "$nodejs_version"'
```

I could not bring myself to keep all the newlines in your diagnostic messages.

Tangentially see also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) which explains why I changed the variables with the container name and the Node version to lower case.

Comment: Nothing here seems to require Bash but perhaps the file you source contains some Bash-only stuff...? Otherwise probably prefer `sh`

Comment: "you need to start a new Bash shell with the correct options to read .bashrc" what would be this correct options? How could I do that?

Comment: The Bash man page has the excruciating details, but in brief, I would recommend against that in favor of using a script, as already outlined in this answer.

Comment: I tried to move it into a script but the `source` command still doesn't work. I've created [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73605322/how-to-make-source-command-work-in-a-script-executed-by-docker-exec) to address specifically this matter. Anyhow, thank you for your help so far. I really appreciate it.