# how to make source command work in a script executed by docker exec?

Tags: bash, docker

this is `my-script.sh` content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -o pipefail

echo 'echo "sefo: .bashrc sourced!"' >> ~/.bashrc

echo '=== sourcing .bashrc ...'
source ~/.bashrc
```

On running:

```bash
docker container exec "$container_name" bash /root/my-script.sh
```

I expect to see on the screen `sefo: .bashrc sourced!` but I don't get nothing.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly *doing it wrong* if you are trying to use the interactive features of Bash inside a Docker container. Just put the commands you need to run in the script which needs them, or save them in a file you can `source` from several scripts inside your image if you have code you need to reuse in them.

[The *Startup Files* section of the Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) explains how to force interactive behavior, but really, use a noninteractive script instead unless you are specifically trying to affect the interactive behavior of the shell.

The behavior you are observing is *probably* down to `.bashrc` containing a snippet near the beginning which forces it to abandon the rest of the file if invoked non-interactively. This is not a built-in feature of Bash itself, but many distributions of Bash ship with an `/etc/skel/.bashrc` or similar with a stanza like

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

(This particular example is from Debian.)

This should again convince you that you are doing something wrong if you want to use `.bashrc` for noninteractive things.